# Is there a nice form to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor\sqrt{ r^2-k^2 }\right\rfloor$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left\lfloor\sqrt{ r^2-k^2 }\right\rfloor$$

where $r$ is a constant (not necessarily an integer). Note that $r\ge n$ and both $r, n$ are positive.

---

I apologize if I'm not able to contribute a lot to this problem as the floor function is really weird to me. I have never seen this inside a summation and don't know what to make of this problem. If anything, can one at least place bounds on this summation?

I know that the floor function is defined to satisfy the following property:

If $x:=\left\lfloor n \right\rfloor$, then

$$x-1<n\le x$$

---

How should I proceed? Are there any properties that I should know about when dealing with floor functions in summations?

---

UPDATE: Thank you for the answer. Are there bounds that I can place around the summation that get more accurate as $n$ gets larger?

Comment: Is $r$ an integer? If so, both $r$ and $k$ are integers, so $r^2-k^2$ is an integer, which means $\lfloor r^2-k^2\rfloor = (r^2-k^2)$.

Comment: $r$ doesn't have to be an integer. I'll edit that.

Comment: If $r$ is not an integer, then the expression $$\sum_{k=1}^r (\dots)$$ is not defined.

Comment: OK now there is an $n$ in the expression? Can you please tell us when your question will take its final form? It's a bit annoying having written an entire answer and finding out that you completely changed the question...

Comment: Final form. Sorry, I'm tired. If $r$ is an integer, the problem would not have needed the floor function.

Comment: @LucienJaccon How do you interpret $\sqrt{r^2-k^2}$ when $n>r$ and thus $r^2-k^2$ can take negative values?

Comment: good point. i'll ad that $r\ge k$

Comment: @LucienJaccon But $k$ is the running index. The condition should be $n\le r$.

Comment: If $n = r\sin \left( {\frac{\alpha }{2}} \right)$ with a fixed $0 < \alpha  < \pi$, then your sum is approximately $\frac{{r^2 }}{4}(\alpha  + \sin \alpha )$ for large $r$.

Comment: how did you get that please? thanks for the answer btw

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{r\sin (\alpha /2)} {\left\lfloor {\sqrt {r^2  - k^2 } } \right\rfloor }  \approx \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{r\sin (\alpha /2)} {\sqrt {r^2  - k^2 } }  \approx \int_0^{r\sin (\alpha /2)} {\sqrt {r^2  - t^2 } {\rm d}t}  \\= r^2 \int_0^{\sin (\alpha /2)} {\sqrt {1 - s^2 } {\rm d}s}  = \frac{{r^2 }}{4}(\alpha  + \sin \alpha )
$$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Consider the $xy$-plane, which contains positive lattice points $(j,k)$ with $j,k\in\Bbb N$. For any fixed $k$, the expression $\lfloor\sqrt{r^2-k^2}\rfloor$ counts the number of positive integers $j\le\sqrt{r^2-k^2}\rfloor$, which is the same as $j^2+k^2\le r^2$. In other words, $\lfloor\sqrt{r^2-k^2}\rfloor$ is the number of positive lattice points at height $k$ inside the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin. The entire sum is therefore the number of positive lattice points of height at most $n$ inside that circle.

There isn't a nice closed formula for that quantity, even when $n\ge r$ so that the height restriction is unnecessary. But it is a standard result that the number of lattice points of a "nice" region is approximately its area. So the number of lattice points will be *approximately* the area of the region $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\colon x\ge0,\, 0\le y\le n,\, x^2+y^2\le r^2\}$, which is (fun calculus problem)
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
\frac{1}{2} \left(n \sqrt{r^2-n^2}+r^2 \arctan\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{r^2-n^2}}\right)\right), &\text{if } n\le r, \\
\dfrac{\pi r^2}4, &\text{if } n\ge r.
\end{cases}
$$